# Using itertools groupby to create a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I'm getting a list of items in the format `parent.id_child.id`, like `1_2`. I tried to group the child's id by parent id, for example:
from the input `['1_2', '2_2', '1_1', '2_1', '1_3']` I need the output `[['1','2','3'], ['1','2']]`.
I have tried this:

```
inputlist = ['1_2', '1_1', '2_1', '1_3', '2_2' ]
outputlist= [item.split('_') for item in inputlist]
outputlist.sort()
final = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(outputlist, lambda x: x[0])]
```

This groups the elements correctly, by I need to obtain only the second element of each item. How can I achieve this? Also, can I do the whole thing in a single list comprehension sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, yes; the values themselves are passed into each group iterator unchanged so you need to select again:

```
final = [[g[1] for g in group] for key, group in itertools.groupby(outputlist, lambda x: x[0])]
```

You can do the whole thing in a single expression by nesting the splitting into the `groupby` call, but this becomes rather ugly fast, even when split across multiple lines:

```
final = [
    [g[1] for g in group]
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(item.split('_') for item in inputlist),
        lambda x: x[0])]
```

You could avoid sorting the whole input list and only sort the smaller groups by using a dictionary to do the grouping. Dependending on the size of your ids, you may want to sort your ids *numerically* as well (since text sorting is done lexicographically):

```
per_parent = {}
for item in inputlist:
    parent, child = item.split('_', 1)
    per_parent.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
final = [children for parent, children in sorted(
    per_parent.items(), key=lambda pc: int(pc[0]))]
```

In Python 2, use `iteritems()` rather than `items()` to avoid building an intermediate list.